# Running Ansible playbook with ant commands in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I'm making a playbook to automatize a environment installation. At the moment I'm testing some scripts made by a co-worker and I just want jenkins to run ant commands to check if the scripts structure are correct. This scripts are located in the target machine, since that we just want to test them and there is no need to copy files from a machine to another if the scripts are not correct.

In my Jenkins I configured the jdk and ant version recomended to deploy the requested environment after create a parameterized fresstyle job. My task to run is:

```
---
- name: compile all
  shell: ant all
  args:
    chdir: "{{ env_home }}/Project/scripts"

- name: Create project tables
  shell: ant create-project-tables
  args:
    chdir: "{{ env_home }}/Project/scripts"
```

This is the first role containing at least one ant command to run on target. Ho ever jenkins always returns

```
TASK [build_all : compile all] *****************************************
task path: /opt/testes/env-deployment/roles/build_all/tasks/main.yml:2
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ buildPrepaidAll }}
fatal: [srv1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ant all", "delta": "0:00:00.003675", "end": "2018-11-07 15:55:15.917745", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2018-11-07 15:55:15.914070", "stderr": "/bin/sh: ant: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: ant: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Jenkins does not complain about anything else, just ant command not found and if I type `ant all` in the same folder the command runs

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, your Jenkins job is configured to execute an ansible-playbook which shells out ant calls? Is there a reason to not be using the Jenkins ant plugin (e.g. invoke ant as a build step)? The error is explicit, ant is not available in the PATH for ansible.

Comment: But ant is there. If I run `ant` in my target machine ant would give a error because there was no build.xml on the folder, but would work nontheless. And ant env variable is set and also available in PATH.
But you gave me an idea. /if the target machine has all set including ant, env var and PATH, then might be the source of the bash_profile. Gonna test it and will give feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use the **Ant Plugin** or make sure that the `ant` executable is available in the `ansible` runtime `$PATH`.

### Ant Plugin solution

Add **Invoke Ant** as a **Build step** of in your jobs configuration (**Jenkins Ant Plugin**):

[image: add an **Invoke Ant** build step to your Jenkins job configuration]

[image: configure the ***Invoke Ant** build step]

[image: build your job]

**Note**: this example is running on master. The `ant` executable is that which is defined in the **Global Tool Configuration**. `ant` is not set in the jenkins users `$PATH`, jenkins uses the `ant` executable configured for the job.

[image: Jenkins **Global Tool Configuration**]

If Jenkins is configured to build on remote nodes and if the `ant` installation is not available in the same location defined in the Jenkins **Global Tool Configuration** you need to override the `ant` executable location in the **Node Properties** > **Tool Locations** of the node configuration ...

[image: node configuration <code>ant</code> executable location override]

[image: node build with overridden <code>ant</code> executable location]

### Ansible solution

To understand this solution you need to understand the error. Ref. your (redacted) comment:

> But ant is there. If I run ant in my target machine ant would give a error because there was no build.xml on the folder, but would work nontheless. And ant env variable is set and also available in PATH. But you gave me an idea. /if the target machine has all set including ant, env var and PATH, then might be the source of the bash_profile. ...

Ansible connections are non-interactive, you can see this in the debug trace when using `-vvvv` with your ansible commands, a redacted example:

`<172.28.128.13> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/bmassey/.ansible/cp/881b67b3d5 172.28.128.13 '/bin/sh -c '...'`

`.bash_profile` commands are not executed during non-interactive logins. From `man bash`:

```
An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.  PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.
...
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

You need to ensure that the `ant` executable is available in the `ansible` executables `$PATH`, how you do this is irrelevant, i.e. editing a `profile` from which commands are executed during non-interactive shell logins or setting the environment with `ansible` (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)

```
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    PATH: '/opt/ant/apache-ant-1.10.5/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}'
```

Without `ant` in the `ansible` executables `$PATH`:
[image: no <code>ant</code> in <code>$PATH</code>]

With `ant` in the `ansible` executables `$PATH` set using `ansible`'s `environment` keyword:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  environment:
  - PATH: '/opt/ant/apache-ant-1.10.5/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}'
  tasks:
  - name: execute ant build
    local_action:
      module: shell
      args: ant
      chdir: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/workspace/example"
    register: ant_build

  - debug: var=ant_build.stdout_lines
```

[image: with <code>ant</code> in <code>$PATH</code>]

Slightly modified `ansible-playbook` executed through Jenkins with `ant` in the `ansible` executables `$PATH` set using `ansible`'s `environment` keyword:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  environment:
  - PATH: '/opt/ant/apache-ant-1.10.5/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}'
  tasks:
  - name: execute ant build
    local_action:
      module: shell
      args: ant
      chdir: "{{ lookup('env', 'WORKSPACE') }}"
    register: ant_build
    ...
```

[image: <code>jenkins</code> -> <code>ansible</code> -> <code>ant</code> execution]

Comment: If its a playbook, invoking or configuring ant will not work. I tried to do it and still not working. The ansible solution is the one suitable for me. if you dont want to use the ansible var to load the env vars then set the ant home in the global environment vars and sending the command `ant all` will work

Comment: @FábioCaramelo not quite sure I understand your comment. I updated my answer with an end-to-end example if that can help.

Comment: Just check it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: how can we monitor the shell output continuously until the process exists - whether successfully or in a failure?

 - debug: var=ant_build.stdout_lines

I used the following:
    - name: check on an async task    
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ install_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: ant_build
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 200
      delay: 50

But this does not display the shell output into Ansible execution log

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully to masseyb I found the problem. In my target machine I have ant installed and created the ANT_HOME and added the ANT_HOME/bin to the PATH.

However because this is declared on bash_profile jenkins does not recognize the command because it does not make the source of bash profile, so I added `source {{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bash_profile &&` before the ant command so jenkins user can source the environment variables necessary to run the commands

Comment: It is not jenkins that does not recognize the `ant` command rather it is `ansible` that does not recognize the `ant` command. The execution order is jenkins -> ansible -> ant. Provided that the location of your tools are configured in the **Global Tools Configuration** then jenkins will have no problem finding either `ant` or `ansible` however this does not imply that the `$PATH` set by jenkins is the same `$PATH` available to processes spawned by jenkins. The issue in this case is the connection types established by `ansible` (non-interactive shells) do not execute `.bash_profile` commands.

Comment: You can remove Jenkins from the equation and the error would persist as it's `ansible` and operating system configuration related. With that said, if you're going to use Jenkins then I would suggest using the **Ant Plugin** rather than using the **Ansible Plugin** to shell out `ant` executions - keep a clear distinction between `ant`'s role and `ansible`'s role in your build process.